# Open CV Python- Image distortion radial and perspective-

Tags: python, opencv, perspective, distortion

I have a distorted picture, where without distortion the point A, B C and D form a square of 1 cm * 1 cm.

[image]

I tried to use homography to correct it, but it distort the line AD and BC, as you can see in the figure.

[image]

Do you have an idea how could I correct that?

Thanks a lot!

Marie- coder beginner

PS: for info, the image is taken in a tube with an endoscope camera having a large field of view allowing to take picture of the tube almost around the camera. I will use the 1*1 cm square to estimate roots growth with several pictures taken over time.

here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__' :

# Read source image.
im_src = cv2.imread('points2.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
# Four points of the miniR image
pts_src = np.array([[742,223],[806,255],[818,507],[753,517]], dtype=float)



# Read destination image.
im_dst = cv2.imread('rectangle.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) 
# Four points of the square
pts_dst = np.array([[200,200],[1000,200],[1000,1000],[200,1000]], dtype=float)


# Calculate Homography
h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)

# Warp source image to destination based on homography
im_out = cv2.warpPerspective(im_src, h, (im_dst.shape[1],im_dst.shape[0]))

cv2.imwrite('corrected2.jpg', im_out)



# Display images
cv2.imshow("Source Image", im_src)
cv2.imshow("Destination Image", im_dst)
cv2.imshow("Warped Source Image", im_out)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A homography is a projective transformation. As such it can only map straight lines to straight lines. The straight sides of your input curvilinear quadrangle are correctly rectified, but there is no way that you can straighten the curved sides using a projective transform.

In the photo you posted it may be reasonable to assume that the overall geometry is approximately a cylinder, and the "vertical" lines are parallel to the axis of the cylinder. So they are approximately straight, and a projective transformation (the camera projection) will map them to straight lines. The "horizontal" lines are the images of circles, or ellipses if the cylinder is squashed. A projective transformation will map ellipses (in particular, circles) into ellipses. So you could proceed by fitting ellipses. See [this other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/654276) for hints.

Comment: Thanks Francesco, do you have any idea about how I could do distort the line?

Comment: You need a model of the curve or surface, no? I'd start with a cylinder. BTW, it's nice to upvote or accept an answer if you find it useful.

Comment: I need a model that uncurve my resulting image or a model that uncurve and remove my perspective.

Comment: Edited with further comments.

Comment: Thanks Francesco. I am a bit confused,if I map my ellipse into another ellipse, my lines will still be curved, isn' it? Sorry, I think I did not get it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using GDAL. We can use two chessboard images. One image is imaged with the device creating the distortion and remain unchanged - so with no distortion. With the help QGIS you create a file with associating distorted point to undistorted one. For that you add a Ground Control Point at each intersection using a defined grid interval (e.g. 100px) and export the resulting GCPs as `pointsfile.points`.

After that, you can use a batch file that a collaborator created [here](https://github.com/jonnyhuck/EnRoot). It is using GDAL to geo-correct the images.

You just need to  put the images that you would like to transform (jpg format) into the root directory of the repo and run bash warp.sh. This will output the re-transformed images into the out/ directory.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).